# Preview of Pdf is not getting displayed in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, dam

I am using "granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fileupload" to upload a PDF in the dialog and put a restriction on mime type so that only PDF can be allowed.

Now when i upload a PDF and again reopen the dialog, The preview of the thumbnail of PDF is not getting displayed in the component dialog.

I am also trying to put sizeLimit on the dialog.But not working.

Please help.

Comment: can you verify if the thumbail generation process step is getting executed while DAM update Asset workflow runs?

Comment: Yes , Thumbnails are there.But i think problem is I am not allowing mimeType image and that's why it is not showing up.And if i allow ,User can also add images in the dialog.I don't want that either.

Comment: same issue cannot find a resolution

Comment: Hello @ShivaniGarg did you fix this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

When ever you update the asset, The dam update asset workflow (`/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html`) is triggered. There is a step in the workflow to create the thumbnail. Make sure that step exists and the workflow is triggered when you update an asset.[workflow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0olU2.png)